# Freezing after ubuntu 20.04 upgrade

Tags: 20.04

I upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 LTS to ubuntu 20.04.1 then my computer suddenly started freezing. It will work for a minute then anything i was doing on the computer will freeze. the mouse cursor can move but i can do anything. I HAVE to USE  CTRL-ALT-F1 THEN LOGIN THEN, IT WILL WORK FOR A MINUTE then freeze again . my cpu is amd 4300 and graphics is ati 5300 series. Can somebody help me please.

@heynnema

my computer has

```
AMD cpu- FX4300 quadcore
ATI Radeon HD 5430
Gigabyte motherboard-GA-970A-DS3P
AMD 970/SB950/rev 1.0
```

~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

F1

~$ sudo lshw -c memory

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: F1
       date: 04/08/2013
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 192KiB
       capacity: 192KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2c
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: Dimm0_PartNum
          vendor: Dimm0_Manufacturer
          physical id: 0
          serial: Dimm0_SerNum
          slot: Node0_Dimm0
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
          product: BLS8G3D1609DS
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 1
          serial: A5063A4D
          slot: Node0_Dimm1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: Dimm2_PartNum
          vendor: Dimm2_Manufacturer
          physical id: 2
          serial: Dimm2_SerNum
          slot: Node0_Dimm2
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: Dimm3_PartNum
          vendor: Dimm3_Manufacturer
          physical id: 3
          serial: Dimm3_SerNum
          slot: Node0_Dimm3
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema   did you see results of the commands?

Comment: @heynnema    emma@emma-new:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       1.6Gi       4.7Gi       119Mi       1.5Gi       5.8Gi
Swap:          21Gi          0B        21Gi
emma@emma-new:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
emma@emma-new:~$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=fc6f6ee1-8b9f-4ad8-89a2-41e9b7741410 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: @heynnema   ---emma@emma-new:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 emma emma 4096 Aug 30  2019 .
drwx------ 4 emma emma 4096 Aug 14 09:10 ..
drwxrwxr-x 7 emma emma 4096 Aug  9 11:42 apt-update-indicator@franglais125.gmail.com
emma@emma-new:~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 31 12:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 10 22:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 12 11:27 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 31 12:29 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com

Comment: @heynnema   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 31 12:29 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

Comment: Thank you for the information. Normally that kind of data gets edited into your question, as reading it in the comments is very difficult. Other than a slightly excessive swap, everything else looks ok. Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Also show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: @heynnema-- Thank you for your reply . I have edited the question and added the results of the commands. I am a newbie here so I will I will get better at using this platform. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

Gigabyte motherboard-GA-970A-DS3P

You have BIOS version F1.

There's a newer BIOS available, version F2j, for motherboard rev 1.x, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-970A-DS3P-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios).

[image]

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model version #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Note: For revision 2.x motherboard, see [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-970A-DS3P-rev-2x/support#support-dl-bios).

**Memory**

Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility issues.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

CPU Support List: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-970A-DS3P-rev-10/support#support-cpu

Memory Support List: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-970A-DS3P-rev-10/support#support-doc

**Update #1:**

To check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: @heynnema-- Thank you again. I am going to follow your suggestions. will keep you posted. ps I never had these problem with ubuntu 18.04. now i use ctrl-alt-f1 every few seconds before wruting anything.

Comment: @EDDIE1 Status please...

Comment: ---did a bios update to F2j and everything became worse , could not boot up , tried to repair GRUB , no luck , ended up reinstalling 20.04.1 and ended up losing my data. It became a clean install . Iwill never do an ubuntu upgrade again. Luckily for me I have a abackup cloned disk from a month ago.This is a lesson for me . I think 20.04 is problematic when you do an upgrade.

Comment: @EDDIE1 Sorry to hear about your troubles. As I indicated, backups before a BIOS update is important. It sounds like you had some kind of problem before the upgrade, and the upgrade and later BIOS only made it worse. Do run `memtest`. Do you know how to `fsck` your HDD/SSD?

Comment: @heynnema--yes I did memtest at least 2 passes- no problem .I kept on getting --unknown filesystem . and grub rescue and grub prompt anytime i booted up . i tried to repair grub , no luck. Finally i tried to reinstall 20.04.1 and noticed  that it said  there was no operating system on the harddrive. so my OS had been hosed apparently. When i did the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.1 it saw that there was another os on the harddrive , this time it said there was no OS, and i continued to install and it turned out to be a clean install---all previous data gone. Finally i do not know how to fsck HDD

Comment: @EDDIE1 Yes, as I suspected... you had problems before the upgrade. A clean install was the right thing to do. `memtest` really needs to run all 4 passes to fully check your memory... and with the Ryzen processor, you really need to do that. See Update #1 in my answer for how to `fsck` your HDD/SSD.